# Is this uploading script correct?

Tags: php

I have a folder known as "Mobile_App" and in that folder is a html page which contains a file input, a php script which uploads files, and a folder known as "ImageFiles".

The problem is that the files are not being uploaded into the "ImageFiles". What I want to know is that is the code below correct when it comes to uploading a file into the "Imagefiles" folder or is it incorrect and how can I get it working correctly?

Below is the php script which uploads a file (the file input is known as "fileImage"):

```
<?php

   $destination_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/ImageFiles";

   $result = 0;

   $target_path = $destination_path . basename( $_FILES['fileImage']['name']);

   if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileImage']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
      $result = 1;
   }

   sleep(1);

?>
```

Comment: So what does happen when you run the script?

Comment: When I run the script it just comes with a blank page

Comment: Have you tried `error_reporting()`?

Comment: I will try the error_reporting, I don't know why the file is going into the ImageFiles folder after uploading because I tried the answer from blake305 but no file is being uploaded into the ImageFiles folder. The neccessary permissions have been set because I asked the person who organises the server to make sure that the scripts and all the folders are set correctly to allow uploading and deleting files

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there anything missing in this file upload script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10110237/is-there-anything-missing-in-this-file-upload-script)

Comment: The only reason it wasn't working is because there was no slash between the folder and the file.  The script had `/ImageFilesFilename` as the destination instead of `/ImageFiles/Filename`.  Also, document root isn't necessary at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you have no `/` between the folder name and the file name.  Secondly, you don't need to have the document root.  Corrected code:

```
<?php

   $destination_path = "/ImageFiles";

   $result = 0;

   $target_path = $destination_path . "/" . basename( $_FILES['fileImage']['name']);

   if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileImage']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
      $result = 1;
   }

   sleep(1);

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

No. You haven't checked at all if the upload succeeded or failed. You also don't check for filename collisions and your script will happilly overwrite any existing file with the new one.

```
<?php

if ($_FILES['fileImage']['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
   die("Upload failed with error code " . $_FILES['fileImage']['error']);
}

...
$target_path = etc...
...
if (file_exists($target_path)) {
   die("$target_path exists already");
}
// got here, must be ok to proceed
if (move_uploaded_file(....)) {
etc...
```

The upload error codes are [defined here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php).